# Grouping similar rows next to each other in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have no idea how to explain this well, so please bear with me.

I am trying to group similar rows that are right next to each other, essentially ignoring the n+1th row if it's the same. I'm not sure if this is easy to do in MySQL or not. These rows share no other attribute other than the description. If there are other duplicate "descriptions" that are NOT next to each other, I still want them to be returned.

I have a table full of entries similar to this:

```
+--+-------------------------+
|id|description              |
+--+-------------------------+
| 1|hello                    |
+--+-------------------------+
| 2|foobar                   |  \_   Condense these into one row
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 3|foobar                   |
+--+-------------------------+
| 4|hello                    |
+--+-------------------------+
| 5|world                    |  \__   Condense these into a row
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 6|world                    |
+--+-------------------------+
| 7|puppies                  |
+--+-------------------------+
| 8|kittens                  |  \__   These too...
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 9|kittens                  |
+--+-------------------------+
|10|sloths                   |
+--+-------------------------+
|11|kittens                  |
+--+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a clever trick.  The trick is to count the number of descriptions up to a particular id that are *different* from the description at that `id`.  For values in a sequence, this number will be the same.

In MySQL you can do this count using a correlated subquery.  The rest is just grouping by this field to bring the values together:

```
select min(id) as id, description, count(*) as numCondensed
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table t2
              where t2.id <= t.id and t2.description <> t.description
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by description, grp;
```