# Group records by certain fields but only if they're "next" to each other

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to group records in a table based on some odd requirements. I've gotten very close to what I need, but I can't get the last bit.

```
ID  Task    Time
1   Task1   6:00 AM
1   Task1   6:05 AM
1   Task1   6:10 AM
1   Task2   6:15 AM
1   Task2   6:20 AM
1   Task1   6:30 AM
2   Task1   9:00 AM
2   Task1   9:05 AM
2   Task2   9:10 AM
```

I need Tasks grouped BUT not if they're from a different ID, AND not if they aren't "next" to each other, AND I only want to return the latest Time for a group of Tasks.

So, the results of the above should look like this:

```
ID  Task    Time
1   Task1   6:10 AM
1   Task2   6:20 AM
1   Task1   6:30 AM
2   Task1   9:05 AM
2   Task2   9:10 AM
```

I've figured out the grouping by Task/ID and getting the latest Time parts, but not the part about only grouping them if they're "next" to each other (i.e. not separated by a different Task).

Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT ID, Task, MAX(Time) AS Latest FROM
(SELECT ID, Task, Time FROM TaskTable)
GROUP BY ID, Task
```

This produces the following:

```
ID  Task    Time
1   Task2   6:20 AM
1   Task1   6:30 AM
2   Task1   9:05 AM
2   Task2   9:10 AM
```

As you can see, all of the Task1's from ID 1 are grouped under the latest Time, instead of showing me the two separate times that it ran (before and after Task2).

Oh yeah, and this SQL has to work in Access.... so there's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample provided by Gordon Linoff and the answer from this question: [Grouping similar rows next to each other in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865099/grouping-similar-rows-next-to-each-other-in-mysql) (which were close but not quite there), I was able to piece together a solution which met my needs precisely. It is as follows:

```
select id, task, max(time)
from (select t.*,
          (select count(*)
           from TEST t2
           where t2.time < t.time and t2.task <> t.task
          ) as grp
      from TEST t
     ) t
group by id, task, grp
order by max(time)
```

This produces the desired results shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This is challenging in any database, and more so in MS Access, with its limited implementation of modern SQL functions.

But, there is a way.  Use a correlated subquery to count the number of *dissimilar tasks* before any given task.  While the tasks are the same, this is a constant, which can then be used for aggregation.

```
select task, mint(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from tasks as t2
              where t2.task <> t.task and
                    t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.time < t.time
             ) as grp
      from tasks as t
     ) as t
group by grp, task
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same incorrect result as above: only four records, with the Task1 at 6:10 AM being excluded. Your query also doesn't differentiate between the same Tasks being run under different IDs (which is necessary).