# mongolDB aggregation grouping similar documents next to each other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongoDB that everyday a document with sampling data is added to it. I want to observe fields changes.

I want to use mongoDB aggregation to group similar items next to each  other to the first:

```
+--+-------------------------+
|id|field             | date |
+--+-------------------------+
| 1|hello             | date1|
+--+-------------------------+
| 2|foobar            | date2|  \_   Condense these into one row with date2
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 3|foobar            | date3|
+--+-------------------------+
| 4|hello             | date4|
+--+-------------------------+
| 5|world             | date5|  \__   Condense these into a row with date5
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 6|world             | date6|
+--+-------------------------+
| 7|puppies           | date7|
+--+-------------------------+
| 8|kittens           | date8|  \__   Condense these into a row with date8
+--+-------------------------+  /
| 9|kittens           | date9|
+--+-------------------------+
```

Is it possible to create a mongoDB aggregation for this problem?

Here is answer to similar problem in MySQL:
[Grouping similar rows next to each other in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865099/grouping-similar-rows-next-to-each-other-in-mysql)

## Sample Data

Data are already sorted by date.

These documents:

```
{ "_id" : "566ee064d56d02e854df756e", "date" : "2015-12-14T15:29:40.432Z", "score" : 59 },
{ "_id" : "566a8c70520d55771f2e9871", "date" : "2015-12-11T08:42:23.880Z", "score" : 60 },
{ "_id" : "566932f5572bd1720db7a4ef", "date" : "2015-12-10T08:08:21.514Z", "score" : 60 },
{ "_id" : "5667e652c021206f34e2c9e4", "date" : "2015-12-09T08:29:06.696Z", "score" : 60 },
{ "_id" : "5666a468cc45e9d9a82b81c9", "date" : "2015-12-08T09:35:35.837Z", "score" : 61 },
{ "_id" : "56653fe099799049b66dab97", "date" : "2015-12-07T08:14:24.494Z", "score" : 60 },
{ "_id" : "5663f6b3b7d0b00b74d9fdf9", "date" : "2015-12-06T08:49:55.299Z", "score" : 60 },
{ "_id" : "56629fb56099dfe31b0c72be", "date" : "2015-12-05T08:26:29.510Z", "score" : 60 }
```

should group to:

```
{ "_id" : "566ee064d56d02e854df756e", "date" : "2015-12-14T15:29:40.432Z", "score" : 59 }
{ "_id" : "566a8c70520d55771f2e9871", "date" : "2015-12-11T08:42:23.880Z", "score" : 60 }
{ "_id" : "5666a468cc45e9d9a82b81c9", "date" : "2015-12-08T09:35:35.837Z", "score" : 61 }
{ "_id" : "56653fe099799049b66dab97", "date" : "2015-12-07T08:14:24.494Z", "score" : 60 }
```

Comment: How are two rows defined to be *next to each other* ?

Comment: @BatScream - I added sample data. They define next to each other by date.

Comment: Are the records ordered by `date` in `descending` order, before they are grouped?

Comment: @ BatScream - yes. In my aggregation pipeline I have sort.

Comment: What about using `$skip`? https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on using the `aggregation` framework, this could be done by iterating over the cursor and comparing each document to the previous one:

```
var cursor = db.test.find().sort({date:-1}).toArray();
var result = [];
result.push(cursor[0]); //first document must be saved
for(var i = 1; i < cursor.length; i++) {
    if (cursor[i].score != cursor[i-1].score) {
        result.push(cursor[i]);
    }
}
```

result:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "566ee064d56d02e854df756e",
        "date" : "2015-12-14T15:29:40.432Z",
        "score" : 59
    },
    {
        "_id" : "566a8c70520d55771f2e9871",
        "date" : "2015-12-11T08:42:23.880Z",
        "score" : 60
    },
    {
        "_id" : "5666a468cc45e9d9a82b81c9",
        "date" : "2015-12-08T09:35:35.837Z",
        "score" : 61
    },
    {
        "_id" : "56653fe099799049b66dab97",
        "date" : "2015-12-07T08:14:24.494Z",
        "score" : 60
    }
]
```